# Only allow the Paypal payment redirect to a webpage

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have a webpage on my website at www.example.com/complete.html

As it is right now, anyone can access this page by visiting the website through the URL.

When I set up my paypal payment buttons on my website, after the payment is successful, the user is redirected to www.example.com/complete.html

I don't want anyone to be able to access this page unless they are sent their by the paypal system. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

- [Auto Return](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9E900IEX) and note the option to override with parameters you can use to *check or verify* upon return to your site.
- [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/) - which similarly allows you to *check or verify* upon return to your site/`returnUrl`

There are other ways depending on how you implement Paypal, but the idea is similar - you will need to *check or verify data, either from Paypal, or something you expect back (as described in the Auto Return custom variable - e.g. Session ID that you check/compare when user comes back)* before displaying some page on your site.

Hth..